# Redirecting git/github project to fork?

Tags: git, github, npm

If the official 'main' repo of a git project, either in general or in GitHub, has been moved to a new location or to one of its forks, is there a convention, that can be used indicate the new 'main' repo?

I had been thinking of adding a file 'MOVED', with the new URL as text, but if there is already a convention, then I would rather use that. Optionally, does npm recognize any conventions for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no real "hard" convention that I know of. On GitHub, most people seem to:

- [transfer the repo to its new owner](https://help.github.com/articles/transferring-a-repository-owned-by-your-personal-account/)
- ensure that your copy appears as a fork of the "new" repository (possibly by removing it and then forking it from its new location)
- put a message in the README and in the repo description about its new location.

This is for example what happened with OfflineIMAP: [old location](https://github.com/spaetz/offlineimap), [new location](https://github.com/OfflineIMAP/offlineimap).

However I doubt that npm recognizes this. You'll probably have to update the repository URL there.